# Getting extra relationships in the Neo4j query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, traversal

I am new to Neo4j. 
For a given node (say, node 'n'), I am trying to find all other nodes in the graph that are in some way dependent on it. In other words, find nodes in graph who have edges directed towards node 'n'. I am getting correct nodes(lets call them c,d,e)  using the following query:

```
MATCH (depNode)-[r]->(n:AttributeNode)
WHERE n.name='testnode'
RETURN depNode
```

In the original graph, the nodes c and d are connected as well using a relationship. In the result of the above query, I am also receiving that relationship (edge between c and d). How do I get rid of that edge in my output?

Comment: Can you demo the problem at http://console.neo4j.org?init=0
Your query returns only nodes but you as asking about removing a relation from the results. If c,d,e all have outgoing relations to n then your query would return c,d,e irrespective of whether c,d,e are interconnected or not

Answer (score 4):

If I get your question correctly, I think you're already getting the correct answer in tabular form but in the visualization form Neo4j shows the "extra edges". You should check out the tabular form and confirm whether it's correctly showing the desired output or not (which it would be).

What's happening here is the default way how the Neo4j browser works. Whenever you try to retrieve some nodes, it shows all the relationships between the nodes as well. If you want to just visualize the nodes, you cannot do that in the current version of the Neo4j browser. You will have to use visualization tools like Gephi on your database and filter your results accordingly.

Comment: This drove me crazy until I noticed that the tabular form was correct. I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong and getting wrong results. Really cool tool but really annoying and unintuitive behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As of Neo4j `2.2.0.RC1` you can disable the extra relationships being used by setting **`Autocomplete`** to `Off`. The toggle appears at the bottom-right of your result graph and seems to be remembered for future requests.

Comment: This is a very important answer. I was also confused by the actions of the Autocomplete toggle.